# NSStream closing and opening error

Tags: ios, network-programming, nsstream, cfstream

I'm working with NSStream to send and receive single characters over a network connection.
I instantiate the streams both for reading and for writing using `CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToCFHost(...)`.

The basic working mechanism to send and receive is working fine.

Now I want to create the `NSStream` only when I need to send or receive something (usually one time every 2 minutes). The first time I create the streams, send the packet, close it and everything work well. Next I try to recreate the `NSStream` (create a new socket and open the stream on it), the opening function don't work. Since I'm using `netcat` to test it, I see that when I close the stream using `[NSStream close]` method, the connection on the server is not closing. How can I force to close the socket? Or there's a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Are you closing the streams at both ends?

Comment: No. I only close the stream on the iPhone. I cannot close it on the other side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CFWriteStreamSetProperty` and `CFReadStreamSetProperty` to set `kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket` to `kCFBooleanTrue` in order that the underlying socket is closed when the stream is closed.

Comment: I tried this solution but the socket will not close. It is possible that if I'm converting CFReadStreamRef and CFWriteStreamRef to NSOutputStream and NSINputStream it lose the property?

Comment: I solved. I have to open both streams and close both, instead it'll not close.