# How to close NSStream input/output programmatically

Tags: ios, sockets, nsstream

I have an application that connects users to a serve. Users can connect to a host to communicate inserting an IP address and communicate using NSStream. Pressing the connect button starts a connection to the host and the user can receive and send messages.

I want to give a user the ability to disconnect from the server to not listen to pressing a disconnect button. The problem is that I am never able to successfully close the stream.

This is my current implementation:

```
// Create connection "Connect Button"
- (void)initNetworkCommunication:(UIViewController *)sender {
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"123.456.789.123", 80, &readStream, &writeStream);
    inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
    outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];
    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
    controller = sender;
}

// Stop connection "Disconnect Button"
- (void)stopNetworkConnection {
    [inputStream close];
    [outputStream close];
    [inputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [inputStream release];
    [outputStream release];
    inputStream = nil;
    outputStream = nil;
    NSLog(@"Disconnect from stream");
}
```

The flow of operations is as follows:

2. User insert a valid IP address;
3. User press "Connect Button";
4. Everything works fine, connection established and user can send/receive messages;
5. User press "Disconnect Button" and user do not receive messages;
6. User press "Connect Button" but no longer able to connect

I tried this solution but it did not work:

[NSStream closing and opening error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592873/nsstream-closing-and-opening-error)

Thanks in advance for the help